# Problem with scaling in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, numerical-integration, graphics3d

I have an integral given by `intS[zs,c]` and I want to plot the expression `functionS` (which contains `intS[zs,c]`) with respect to another integral function `inta[zs,c]` and `zs`. However, the values of `inta[zs,c]` are extremely small compared to `functionS` so in the `ParametricPlot3D` I got a badly looking plot that looks smashed.

My code is as follows,

```
d = 4;(*dimensions*)
inta[zs_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[((c zs^(d + 1))/(2 d)) (y^((1 - d)/(2 d)))/(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d) y)^(1/2), {y, 0, 1}]
intS[zs_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[((c^2 zs^(2 d))/(d - 1)) (y^d)/(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d) y^(2 d))^(1/2), {y, 0, 1}]
functionS = ((-(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d))^(1/2))/(d - 1) - intS[zs, c] + 1/zs^(d - 1));
function = Log[10, functionS];

ParametricPlot3D[{zs, inta[zs, c], function}, {zs, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, PlotRange -> Full, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> Large] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix `BoxRatios` for 3d plots like this. I am going to show with a simple example

```
ParametricPlot3D[{zs, zs^2, zs + c}, {zs, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Now adjust equal length for each axis with `BoxRatios->{1,1,1}`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{zs, zs^2, zs + c}, {zs, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> 300, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very informative! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can speed up the code by use `Newton-Leibniz Formula` instead of `NIntegrate` since all the functions have symbole expression say `Hypergeometric2F1`

```
Clear["`*"];
d = 4;(*dimensions*)
inta[zs_, c_] = 
 Subtract @@ (Integrate[((c zs^(d + 1))/(2 d)) (y^((1 - 
             d)/(2 d)))/(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d) y)^(1/2), y] /. y -> {1, 0});
intS[zs_, c_] = 
  Subtract @@ (Integrate[((c^2 zs^(2 d))/(d - 1)) (y^
          d)/(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d) y^(2 d))^(1/2), y] /. y -> {1, 0});
functionS = ((-(1 - c^2 zs^(2 d))^(1/2))/(d - 1) - intS[zs, c] + 
    1/zs^(d - 1));
function = Log[10, functionS];
ParametricPlot3D[{zs, inta[zs, c], function}, {zs, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by speed up the code? The calculation?

Comment: @mathemania Yes,speed the calculate.  Sorry for my poor English. Since the two functions's integrate have symbole expression in Mathematica,so it is faster than numeric calculate.

Comment: So how do you do the `Newton-Leibniz Formula` in Mathematica? Also, what is the difference between the code you typed above compared to mine?